# PHP Intl, документация

Tags: php, документация

Есть описание константы

**IntlCalendar::FIELD_MILLISECONDS_IN_DAY**

> Calendar field encompassing
>   the information in  IntlCalendar::FIELD_HOUR_OF_DAY,
>   IntlCalendar::FIELD_MINUTE,  IntlCalendar::FIELD_SECOND and
>   IntlCalendar::FIELD_MILLISECOND.  Range is from the 0 to 24 * 3600 *
>   1000 - 1.  It is not the amount of milliseconds ellapsed in the day
>   since on DST  transitions it will have discontinuities analog to those
>   of the wall time.

Вроде бы понятно, что речь про количество миллисекунд прошедших с момента смены даты, но в последнем абзаце говорится, что это не так. Вот про "discontinuities" и особенно про "the wall time" вааще не въехал.

Comment: Скорее всего имеется в виду то что 1 секунда вычитается что бы иметь разницу с нулевой милисекундой следующего дня.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"the wall time" - эфемизм, означающий "время на настенных часах". Т.е. то время, которое вы ответите, если вас спросят "который час?"

По вопросу в целом можно перевести так:

> В случае перехода на зимнее/летнее время, значения данных полей не будут отражать точного количества прошедшего с полуночи времени.

Т.е. Если в 2 часа ночи часы были переведены на час назад, то в поле FIELD_HOUR_OF_DAY будет содержаться 1, а не 2.